# Убрать каждое n-e письмо в gmail

Tags: javascript, dom, gmail

Как убрать каждое 2e письмо в gmail (входящие)из DOM'а используя только js, таким образом, что бы работало у любого пользователя.

Comment: Вопрос вообще не ясен, когда? где? при каких условиях?

Comment: нужно написать код, который убирает папки входящих писем.
что бы его можно было вставить в консоль и код работал.

Comment: А для чего, если не секрет?